# How to implement site maintenance feature for user oriented sites

Tags: php, session

I have a need for a "site maintenance" feature, as the site admin and developer for a few websites.  These sites are all based on users logging in to get any useful content.  First, the reasons:

1. If a site that I rely on is down (i.e. a payment processor), I'd like to be able to set "maintenance mode" that will disallow logins, to be sure nobody attempts to submit payments during this time.
2. If I am testing a feature I've rolled out (after testing on staging, but before I want to take it 100% live to the public) - I'd like to disallow logins to prevent anyone from seeing a buggy version for a few hours.

My plan is to set a flag in the DB, that the login script checks when a user logs in.  If the flag is set - the user cannot login and will receive an appropriate error message.

However, how do I end the sessions of every currently-logged-in user?

I'm also wondering if this sounds like a bad idea for any reason I may be overlooking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+maintenance+mode

Comment: @MikeB Ah, I searched but couldn't find that!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the second point:

You can set up a different webserver, which could be on the same physical server, but using different prefix path or different port or different domain name, upload the new version in its application root, then test it on the live environment (same server, using the same database etc...). If everything fine, push it to the real live root. This way you won't have downtime.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't log out every user, I would just set a cookie that would allow someone to see the version in maintenance mode, if it doesn't exist don't let them in.

The only reason I would see for this to be a bad idea would be because it might annoy users.